# LINQ to query result from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have all the data elements stored from a resource file as follows:

```
XDocument xDocTranslated = XDocument.Load(TranslatedFile);
var resultTranslated = from item in xDocTranslated.Descendants("data")
select new
{
    Name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
    Value = (string)item.Element("value")
};
```

I have a list of strings that I want to compare against the result above and if they match I want to store the new value.

I'm trying something like this:

```
//Get each string that i want to translate
foreach (var name in StringsToTranslatelist)
{
    //Look up the translated value from data extracted from xml file
    var value= from entry in resultTranslated
        where entry.Name == name;                  <--this does not work

}
```

WHat is the LINQ statement that I should be using here?? How do I search the resultTranslated ??

Comment: What *this does not work* means? Exception?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to get just the matching value for the specified name, in which case you want to use a standard query operator that will return a scalar value, such as `Single`:

```
var value = resultTranslated.Single(r => r.Name == name).Value;
```

`Single` will throw an exception if there is no match or if there is more than one match.

Alternatively, you could use `First` if you want to get the first result (and throw an exception if there are none), or `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` and do null checks yourself depending on your requirements.

Comment: XElement and XAttribute have custom explicit cast operators that will make his code work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to get value by name:

```
foreach (var name in StringsToTranslatelist)
{
    var data =  resultTranslated.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == name);
    if (data != null)
    {
        // match is found, you can use value
        var value = data.Value;
    }
}
```

---

But more efficient way to do this is simply convert you `resultTranslated` to dictionary:

```
var data = resultTranslated.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Then you will be able to get values by name

```
if (data.ContainsKey(name))
    value = data[name];
```

Answer (score 1):

> //Look up the translated value from data extracted from xml file

To me that immediately looks like a dictionary lookup would be the most natural fit.

So the code might be:

```
//creating the dictionary from the xml doc
var resultTranslatedLookup = xDocTranslated.Descendants("data")
                     .ToDictionary(keyItem => keyItem.Attribute("name").Value
                     , valItem => valItem.Element("value").Value);

//now usage
foreach (var name in StringsToTranslatelist)
{
    string result;
    if (resultTranslatedLookup.TryGetValue(name, out result))
    {
        //do your thing
    }
}
```

Hope the ToDictionary call is clear, that's just a key and value selector, equivalent to your select new.